# What's the differences between "quantum"s in htb and fq_codel qdisc?

Tags: linux, networking, tc, htb

According to the manual page

**HTB**

> **quantum**
>   how much bytes to serve from leaf at once {use r2q}

**FQ_Codel**

> **quantum**
>   It is the number of bytes used as 'deficit' in the fair queuing algorithm. Default is set to 1514 bytes which corresponds to the Ethernet MTU plus the hardware header length of 14 bytes.

**Questions:**
1. Are they the same thing?
2. How to configure them to achieve best performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of these parameters are same - how much bytes can be dequeued for single flow before switching to serving of other flow. For the best granularity this value should be near and little bigger than maximum packet size.

HTB has been implemented a long time ago and default `r2q` (rate to quantum) value isn't suitable for current speeds (you can see a lot of messages in the `dmesg` output about `quantum of class ... is big. Consider r2q change`). So better specify it manually with value of 1514 for unification.

Comment: Just curious, why the Ethernet header is 14 bytes long? Isn’t it 22 bytes?